# Hidden Root Browser on MIUI?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, root-access, file-management, miui

I have just installed MIUI on my phone and when I was about to select a picture to attach to a message, I was prompted with the following:

[image]

The thing is, I don't have Root Browser installed. I also can't see it on the list of apps on the MIUI launcher. But it's being offered as an option when I choose files **and** it works. Can anyone explain how this is the case?

Comment: Are you using a custom launcher that allows you to hide apps in the app drawer? (Nova lets you do this)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed you are using MIUI launcher. I don't know what that looks like. But there's probably a setting / screen somewhere that lets you hide the app.

Comment: Do you have ROM Toolbox installed? According to [Root Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.root.browserfree)'s store page, it is included in ROM Toolbox.

Comment: I don't think I have ROM toolbox either. Does MIUI include it by default? I can't see ROM toolbox on the apps either.